# Success message/notification not display on magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I created a module and at admin panel, I submit/save form but they are not showing success notification at the header. Even not showing error/warning notification.

Please, can anybody explain to me that what code I need to write to display the notification?

Answer (score 0):

There can be few possibilities:

- You are using wrong session area to set error/warning notifications, i.e. you are using **`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')`** or **`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')`** to set notification in admin panel module.
- You can also check **`/var/log`** folder after enabling logs generation from admin panel to debug the issue.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: I checked but in log file nothing regarding to this. And i used Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess() method.

Comment: Please, can anybody explain what mistake may be from my side ?

Comment: Guys, I solved it.

Comment: @vijaygupta please add the solution here as well. Thanks